# Google rich snippets organization logo when author defined

Tags: seo, google-plus, integration

Hello I am trying to get working sport club logo in google result. 
I created google plus page for this club and connecting it with

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/112065979798815979924?rel=publisher">
```

show excepted result (at least in webmaster tools)

Trouble gets on the scene when I want also to have autorship (site conncected with private G+ profile) with

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/100752846294347823044?rel=author">
```

In this case club logo dissapears an my (empty) profile picture appears here.

Answer (score 0):

In the real search results publisher logos are not shown yet.

Also, publisher markup is only needed on the home page where author markup generaly does not make sense.